# What's wrong with this method of evaluating an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, indefinite-integrals

I was trying to evalute the integral $$\int \frac{1}{x^2+1} \,dx$$ by partial fractions.

$$\frac{1}{x^2+1} = \frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{x-i} - \frac{1}{x+i}\right)$$

Therefore,
\begin{aligned} \int \frac{1}{x^2+1} \,dx  &= \frac{1}{2i} \int \left(\frac{1}{x-i} - \frac{1}{x+i}\right) \,dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} (\ln(x-i) - \ln(x+i)) \\
&= \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) +C \end{aligned}

Because
$$ x - i = \exp\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+i\arctan{\frac{1}{x}}\right)$$
and
$$ x + i = \exp\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-i\arctan{\frac{1}{x}}\right).$$

This differs from what you get from trigonometric substitution, which is where I'm having difficulties in finding my error.

In the last step, I'm assuming that $\ln(z)$ works as you would expect for complex numbers.

Comment: You have swapped $+$ and $-$ in $\exp$. Thus the answer is $-\arctan \frac{1}{x} + C$  which is the same as $\arctan x + C$

Comment: Also it should be $x - i = \exp(\log \sqrt{x^2+1} - i \arctan(1/x))$ (for $x > 0$).

Comment: How is $\arctan(1/x) = - \arctan(x)$

Comment: No, $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)\pi/2$ for all $x\neq 0$, and you absorb the $\pm\pi/2$ into $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the your fifth equation you will actually get $$I=-\tan^{-1}(1/x)+C$$
and due to the identity:
$$\tan^{-1} x+\tan^{-1} (1/x)= \pi/2$$
We get $$I=\pi/2+\tan^{-1} x+ D$$
Uther wise the standard formula gives $$I=\tan^{-1} x+E$$
These two results differ only by a constant, which is normal in indefinite integration.